# Bash Split CSV by Range

Tags: bash, shell, csv, sh

I  have the following CSV File

```
"Costa Rica","Aberdeen Research",10152
"Costa Rica","Applebees Lab",14562
"Costa Rica","Bride Research",10452
"Costa Rica","Complex Teams",4512
"Costa Rica","Dynamic Air",7854
"Costa Rica","Electronict Arts",7851
```

And i need to split the CSV in N new files based on the first character of the second Column in a **BASH** script

For example the script:

`$: ./split.sh -from A -to C file.csv`

And the expected result must be:

```
"Costa Rica","Aberdeen Research",10152
"Costa Rica","Applebees Lab",14562
"Costa Rica","Bride Research",10452
"Costa Rica","Complex Teams",4512
```

And so on if i pass diferent fisrt letter in -from -to parameters

Thanks

Comment: so not only you filter but you also give a range. It would be good to see your attempts. Also, what happens with the rest of the lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish something like this quite simply with awk.

```
awk -F "," '$2 ~ /^\"[A-C]/' < file.csv
```

Will return:

```
"Costa Rica","Aberdeen Research",10152
"Costa Rica","Applebees Lab",14562
"Costa Rica","Bride Research",10452
"Costa Rica","Complex Teams",4512
```

Note that this is case sensitive, so won't match columns like `"Costa Rica","bird sanctuary",4321`. To do this alter the command to:

```
awk -F "," '$2 ~ /^\"[a-cA-C]/' < file.csv
```

Adapting this to a bash script should be simple enough, consider reading up a little on awk, getopts and regular expression matching.

Comment: ¡Genius! Thanks a lot